# I need to convert 750 jpgs into a single a4 size pdf serially

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, jpeg

I need to convert 750 jpg images into a single a4 size pdf. My problem is page no 10 comes right after page no. 1 :). I tried various combinations of find, ls, grep available on the net. But the pdf come out all mixed up. Is there any command to do the needful?

Comment: Why weren't the files named properly in the first place?

Comment: i downloaded them from some place. page no 2 should come after page no 1...

Answer (score 0):

OK.Here is what I did:
Step 1: Convert all the jpg files into pdf

```
for img in *.jpg; do
    filename=${img%.*}
    convert "$filename.jpg" "$filename.pdf"
done
```

Step 2: Install pdfchain from the ubuntu repos, and start it. It did the job like a hotknife through butter :)

No jumbling of page numbers...